# Send List to server with retrofit:2.1.0 - Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a `ClassSchedule`:

```
public class ClassSchedule {
    private String Day;
    private String Time;

    public String getDay() {
        return Day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        Day = day;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }
}
```

And I set data like:

```
List<ClassSchedule> listSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
ClassSchedule classSchedule = new ClassSchedule();
classSchedule.setDay(weekDay);
classSchedule.setTime(startTime);
listSchedule.add(classSchedule);
```

How I can send `listSchedule` to server with `retrofit:2.1.0`?

Other parameters :

```
    Classes classesme = new Classes();
    classesme.setName(name);
    classesme.setCost(cost);
    classesme.setType(String.valueOf(spCost));
    classesme.setClass_Type(spClass);
    classesme.setProvince(nameState);
    classesme.setCity(city);
    classesme.setField_Name(field);
    classesme.setSection(section);
    classesme.setTerm(term);
    classesme.setYear(year);
    classesme.setAccess_Type(access);
    classesme.setUniversity_Name(nameUn);
    classesme.setDescription(desc);
    classesme.setDayStart(startDate);
    classesme.setDayEnd(endDate);
```

And : 
String username = "Jim";

And in my `interface` is :

```
public interface Interface_CreateClass {
    @POST("SetData/CreateClass")
    Call<JsonGet_CreateClass> getJSONCreateClass(@Query("username") String username,
                                                 @Body Classes classes,
                                                 @Body ClassSchedule classSchedule);
}
```

Comment: you could convert it to a json and then communicate the same to server

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can send it as json on the body by passing `@Body List<ClassSchedule> listSchedule` as a param to the interface.

Comment: I tried @Body ClassSchedule classSchedule but say me Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<....ClassSchedule>', required: '....ClassSchedule'

Comment: I edited my question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to send the list itself as a Body

```
public interface Interface_CreateClass {
    @POST("SetData/CreateClass")
    Call<JsonGet_CreateClass> getJSONCreateClass(@Query("username") String username,
                                                 @Body List<ClassSchedule> classSchedule);
}
```

Notice: I think you can't have two parameters annotated as `Body` in the same request.

Comment: Get me Multiple "@Body method annotations found. (parameter #3)" but I need to "@Body Classes classes" for send other data !

Comment: You can't send two Bodys. That makes no sense! You can wrap the two on another class and send it as `Body`