# List View with Accept and Decline a request Buttons in each Row in android (Rest Api)

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-json

I am developing an Android application based on REST API remote data, in which I have made one `ListView` with two buttons, "Accept" and "Decline".

When the user selects the "Accept" button, certain portions of the `JSON` property have to change to `true` and if they select the "Decline" button, certain portions of the `JSON` property have to change to `false` and `@POST` it.

How can I do it?

**What I have done so far:**

My main activity:

```
public class ViewRefundRequest extends AppCompatActivity{

    ProgressBar progressBarVRR;
    private ListView viewRefundRequestListView;
    RelativeLayout vrrMainLayout;

    ApiService serviceVRR;
    TokenManager tokenManagerVrr;

    Call<List<ViewRefundRequestModel>> callViewRefundRequestData;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_refund_request);

        tokenManagerVrr = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
        serviceVRR = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManagerVrr);

        progressBarVRR = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.viewRefundRequestProgressBar);
        viewRefundRequestListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewRefundRequestListView);

        //Rest Api call
        allViewRefundRequestData();
    }

    private void updateUI(List<ViewRefundRequestModel> VrrModel) {

        AdminViewRefundRequestAdapter adapterVrr = new AdminViewRefundRequestAdapter(VrrModel, this);
        viewRefundRequestListView.setAdapter(adapterVrr);

    }

    private void allViewRefundRequestData() {
        progressBarVRR.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        callViewRefundRequestData = serviceVRR.getAllViewRefundRequest();
        callViewRefundRequestData.enqueue(new Callback<List<ViewRefundRequestModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<List<ViewRefundRequestModel>> call, @NotNull Response<List<ViewRefundRequestModel>> response) {
                progressBarVRR.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){

                    updateUI(response.body());

                }else {

                    if (response.code() == 401) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(ViewRefundRequest.this, LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                        tokenManagerVrr.deleteToken();
                        Toast.makeText(ViewRefundRequest.this, "User session expired, Login again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<List<ViewRefundRequestModel>> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                progressBarVRR.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Network Status: " + t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f5003d"));
                TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (callViewRefundRequestData != null) {
            callViewRefundRequestData.cancel();
            callViewRefundRequestData = null;
        }
    }

}
```

My adapter class:

```
public class AdminViewRefundRequestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<ViewRefundRequestModel> viewRefundRequestModels;
    private Context context;

    public AdminViewRefundRequestAdapter(List<ViewRefundRequestModel> viewRefundRequestModels, Context context) {
        this.viewRefundRequestModels = viewRefundRequestModels;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return viewRefundRequestModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {      

        return viewRefundRequestModels.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.model_view_refund_reques, viewGroup, false);
        }

        TextView patient_name = view.findViewById(R.id.patient_name_VRR_Model);
        TextView patient_id = view.findViewById(R.id.patient_id_VRR_Model);
        TextView item_name = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name_VRR_Model);
        TextView category = view.findViewById(R.id.category_VRR_Model);
        TextView quantity = view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_VRR_Model);
        TextView amount = view.findViewById(R.id.amount_VRR_Model);
        TextView discount = view.findViewById(R.id.discount_VRR_Model);
        TextView amount_after_discount = view.findViewById(R.id.amount_after_discount_VRR_Model);
        TextView refund_note = view.findViewById(R.id.refund_note_VRR_Model);

        Button make_decisionBtn_Yes = view.findViewById(R.id.make_decisionBtn01_VRR_Model);
        Button make_decisionBtn_No = view.findViewById(R.id.make_decisionBtn02_VRR_Model);

        make_decisionBtn_Yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //accept the request and make the certain portion of the Json Object property to true
            }
        });

        make_decisionBtn_No.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //accept the request and make the certain portion of the Json Object property to false
            }
        });

        final ViewRefundRequestModel thisModelResponse = viewRefundRequestModels.get(position);

        Patient patient = thisModelResponse.getPatient();
        String patientName= patient.getFirstName()+" "+patient.getLastName();

        Item item =thisModelResponse.getItem();
        String itemName= item.getName();

        ItemCategory itemCategory = item.getItemCategory();
        String itemCategoryName = itemCategory.getName();

        patient_name.setText(patientName);
        patient_id.setText(Integer.toString(thisModelResponse.getPatientID()));
        item_name.setText(itemName);
        category.setText(itemCategoryName);
        quantity.setText(Integer.toString(thisModelResponse.getServiceQuantity()));
        amount.setText(Double.toString(thisModelResponse.getServiceActualPrice()));
        discount.setText(Double.toString(thisModelResponse.getDiscount()));
        amount_after_discount.setText(Double.toString(thisModelResponse.getServiceListPrice()));
        refund_note.setText(thisModelResponse.getRefundNote());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Have to change this portion of the JSON file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all your must change your implementation and use `RecyclerView`. Also, ViewRefundRequestModel is an Object so you map it in `List` as I see. You can change the state of the field `RefundStatus` depending the button. The latter must be done inside `onBindViewHolder` of the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Please search for the implementation of the `RecyclerView`. To sum up, I assume that you can send your List with the post .

Comment: You can use `retrofit`

Comment: Yes, I'm using retrofit indeed, but my question is how to modify that data that i'm getting and send or post it back from the adapter with targeting specific user id? please see the picture

Comment: Example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187238/send-list-to-server-with-retrofit2-1-0-android

Comment: Still didn't find any solution